# Recurrence of T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3)

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I've searched online for this but I only seem to find answers for a similar equation:

```
T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + cn
```

But the one I'm trying to solve is:

```
T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3)
```

Base case: We can assume `T(a) = Theta(1)` for any constant `a`.

I've succeeded in proving (by induction) that `T(n) = O(n*log(n))`. I thought the answer should be `Theta(n*log(n))`, but I cannot prove that `T(n) = Omega(n*log(n))`.

So my question is - am I correct that the answer is `O(n*log(n))`, and NOT `Theta(n*log(n))`? IF that's true that would really be great...

If I'm wrong I will of course explain where I'm stuck in the induction process...

Thanks!

P.S. If you need to, please try to explain using induction, because I haven't learned all methods for solving these problems yet.

Comment: What is the base case? Also, this is probably better suited for http://mathematics.stackexchange.com or http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math and not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove that it's Omega(n log n) because T(n) = n satisfies the base case and the recurrence.